# Converting and Returning list in WCF

Tags: wcf

hi friends
I have been working WCF since past one week. I have written some samples, it contains 2 layers one is business layer and a DAL layer. I want to send list and want to return the list.

Here is the code check out correct the mistakes.

**IEmployee.cs**

```
 [OperationContract]
 List<outEmployee> CreateEmployeeDetails(inemployee InsertEmployee);

 [DataContract]
 public class inemployee
 {
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }    
 }

 public class outEmailTemplate
 {
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
 }
```

**Employee.svc.cs**

```
 public List<outEmployee> CreateEmployeeDetails(inemployee InsertEmployee)
 {
    EmployeeDac emp = new EmployeeDac();
    return emp.InsertEmployeeDetails(InsertEmployee);
 }
```

**EmployeeDac.cs**

```
public List<outEmployee> InsertEmailTemplate(inEmployee InsertEmp)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    SqlCommand cmd;
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_InsertEmployee", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("employeename", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = InsertEmp.Employeename;
    con.Open();
    string id = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
    List<inemployee> oet = new List<inemployee>();
    oet.Add(id);
    return oet;
 }
```

Can anyone please correct the mistakes and rewrite the code.

Here I want to return the list to ui (silverlight).

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error?? If so: **what exactly** is it?? Also - you're showing an `inemployee` and an `outemailtemplate` type, but the type that's being returned by your service, `outemployee` is nowhere......

Comment: getting error on return oet line in employeedac.

Comment: Outemailtemplate is outemployee i forget to change

Comment: why do you allways return (in InsertEmailTemplate) List<outEmployee> with 1 element?

Comment: sorry thats InsertEmployeeDetails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems:

1) your **data contracts are incomplete** - you need to first of all decorate **all** classes used in your service methods (for input **and** output parameters!) with `[DataContract]`, and you should also decorate all members to be serialized with `[DataMember]`:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class inemployee
    {
       [DataMember]
       public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public string EmployeeName { get; set; }    
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class outemployee
    {
       [DataMember]
       public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    }
```

BTW: **why** do you have two separate types - `inemployee` and `outemployee` ?? Wouldn't just one type `Employee` be sufficient??

2) Your DAL layer should embrace best practices: wrap your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into using blocks; for your `VARCHAR` parameter, **always** define a length! and most of all: if you want to return a `List<outemployee>`, you need to create a list of `outemployee` - not of `inemployee`!

And to finish off: you're getting back an `id` of type `string` and you're trying to add that `string` to a `List<outemployee>` - that will **never** work of course! Given the `id`, you need to create an instance of `outemployee` and add **that** to the list.

```
    public List<outEmployee> InsertEmailTemplate(inEmployee InsertEmp)
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_InsertEmployee", con))
        {
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           cmd.Parameters.Add("employeename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = InsertEmp.Employeename;

           con.Open();
           string id = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
           con.Close();
        }

        // you want to return outemployee - 
        // so you need to create an outemployee!
        List<outemployee> oet = new List<outemployee>(); 

        // create a new instance of an "outemployee"
        outemployee emp = new outemployee();

        // set the EmployeeID property of the "outemployee" to "id"
        emp.EmployeeID = id;

        // add new "outemployee" to list
        oet.Add(emp);

        return oet;
    }
```

Comment: no im not creating instance, you said oet.add(id) never works, but i want to return the id to front end. now what can i do

Comment: Marc_s how can convert datatable to list in dac layer for search criteria. now im sending datatable to db and getting the result now i want to convert to list and return that list to front end how can i do that...

Comment: @Raj: ask a new question, please

Comment: okay marc for pervious one without instance creation can u able to return the list.

Comment: okay suppose i want to add the error number(ABC001 from resource file its is created in the client side) in the list and return the list, can u add the it to the list.

Comment: now i want to add both error number and id in the list and return the list.

Comment: @Raj: then you need to extend the class that is being returned, so that it can hold an error code/message, too

Comment: without using the instance can i able to add it in the list in dac layer

Comment: @Raj: no - your list has objects of type `outemployee` - nothing else. You can add none, one, thousands - but it's always going have to be objects of type `outemployee` - you **cannot** suddenly add an error code / message to a `List<outemployee>` - only `outemployee` objects.